# Cant build on openshift jenkins

Tags: jenkins, openshift

I am getting following exception when I try to build project on openshift jenkins

```
Apr 03, 2013 12:08:27 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud provision
INFO: Provisioning new node for workload = 2 and label = null
Apr 03, 2013 12:08:27 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud provision
INFO: Cancelling build - Label is null
Apr 03, 2013 12:08:27 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud cancelBuild
INFO: Cancelling build
Apr 03, 2013 12:08:27 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud cancelItem
INFO: Cancelling Item 
Apr 03, 2013 12:08:27 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud cancelItem
WARNING: Build null rawbldr has been canceled
Apr 03, 2013 12:08:27 PM hudson.triggers.SafeTimerTask run
SEVERE: Timer task hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner$NodeProvisionerInvoker@6d7414 failed
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Label
    at hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud.provision(OpenShiftCloud.java:391)
    at hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.update(NodeProvisioner.java:227)
    at hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.access$000(NodeProvisioner.java:51)
    at hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner$NodeProvisionerInvoker.doRun(NodeProvisioner.java:308)
    at hudson.triggers.SafeTimerTask.run(SafeTimerTask.java:54)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Comment: Any more information you can share? Was it working before? Since when it fails?

Comment: Yes. It worked before. I had 3 successful builds. strange thing is its working for simple new job (doing nothing)

Comment: Did you add a timer trigger? If so, what is the exact configuration. If you remove it, do it work properly again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are in midst of upgrade, that may be the cause here. Please try again after the upgrade is done. For up-to-date status check here: https://openshift.redhat.com/app/status

Answer (score 0):

Issue was I have to "Restrict where this project can be run" and specify label (Earlier it worked without it..may be something else..)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build something on openshift jenkins it need to be connected with jenkins job workspace (you produce it when enabling in your openshift application by using `Enable Jenkins builds` option). Then to automatically created jenkins job option `Restrict where this project can be run` is added and there is placed reference to workspace.

Usually name looks like: {project_name}_build